# Short date, with abbreviated month names

Tags: date, winapi, localization

With Win32 I can use *GetLocaleInfoEx* to fetch locale related date/time format picture strings, i.e. *LOCALE_SSHORTDATE* or *LOCALE_SLONGDATE*.  However there's no enumeration that'll give me a date format with "mmm", or abbreviated month names in the picture.

For example, it's more compact ("en" locale) to write 24 Feb 2016 than 24 February 2016.  I can use *LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME...* to fetch the abbreviated month names for the locale but is it acceptable to simply drop them in place of the long month names when I'm formatting a long date?  Will this break in some locales?

Note that I'm making my own date picker component, not simply wishing to format strings.

Comment: You can use custom picture strings, so if you want "dd mmm yyyy" or whatever, just use that.

Comment: I can but I want to use whatever my current locale thinks I should use.  I'm guessing that MMM format specifier is *only* ever used in custom format pictures anyway, though I can't find any info on this.  In other words to make the date shorter I could just search/replace MMMM with MMM .

Comment: An "abbreviated date format" isn't something that locales provide, so you are really on your own. The search/replace idea is probably as good as you can get.

Comment: Ok, that's all I wanted to know.  Thank you.